# Anaconda3 is giving http 000 error even after ading path

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Installed Anaconda 3 on my i7 3rd generation PC I have windows 10.
when I tried to create a virtual env using conda create -n enviromentname it gave me a proxyerror (I am behind a firewall set up by employer) overcame this problem by overwriting the .condarc file with my proxy address, after that running conda create or conda install gives me http 000 error, seem many answers to this problem here and there, have added anconda3 to my path enviroment variable.
1. user/anaconda3
2.user/anaconda3/scripts
3.user/anaconda3/library/bin
this isn't working.
I have also tried to installed anaconda 32 bit version but that ran into the same problem.
any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to open a command line from the Anaconda3 menu and type your command from here. See the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404276/updating-scikit-learn-to-latest-version-with-anaconda-environment-fails-with-htt